# How does CPU frequency scaling affect code execution?

Tags: performance

### Background

I'm using Intel's DPDK to build a network appliance. Intel DPDK provides code execution on an isolated CPU core for networking applications. **By default DPDK will run the CPU at the maximum frequency**, resulting in maximum power usage. Although the performance is improved and latency is much less with DPDK, the power usage during times the system is not heavily loaded negates a lot of the perofrmance benefits from a cost standpoint. There is a **library for controlling the CPU frequency** in DPDK.

While monitoring the power usage of the machine I can see that reducing the frequency using the provided library is having the desired effect: the power usage drastically reduced.

### Questions

- How long does an Intel (i7, Xeon) CPU take to change frequency?
- Is the change completed at once or as a ramp?
- Is code continuously executed during the change?

Comment: you're right about frequency change that stops cpu execution, my bad.

Comment: Thanks for giving it a shot, I got some good keywords to research from your answer.